# Update/Refresh ListView or ListView Item without starting from the top

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, selecteditem

Is there a way to update/refresh my ListView or ListView Item? Currently the only way to update/refresh my ListView is this:

```
public void NewsList_Selected(Object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var a = e.SelectedItem as NewsEntry;
    var b = from c in newsEntries
            where (a == c)
            select c;
    foreach(NewsEntry d in b)
    {
        d.Text = d.TextFull;
    }

    // Below is my update/refresh thing
    NewsList.ItemsSource = null;
    NewsList.ItemsSource = newsEntries;
 }
```

But that means that if I scroll down in my ListView and select an Item I will jump to the top of my ListView again. But I need to stay at the same spot I left. Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way of doing this is actually using the `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your Model class and using the observable collection as your ListView ItemsSource.

- First,Inherit your class with `INotifyPropertyChanged` and implement its property something like this:

  ```
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;  

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)  
    {  
        if (PropertyChanged != null)  
        {  
           PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));  
        }  
     }
  ```
- Then create a property for your ListView:

  ```
   private ObservableCollection<DataType> _FooCollection;
   public ObservableCollection<DataType> FooCollection { get{return _FooCollection; } set{_FooCollection = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FooCollection )); }}
  ```
- In your Xaml assign this collection as the listview binding :

  ```
   <ListView .... ItemsSource={Binding FooCollection} ..../>
  ```
- Then when you have to make a change in the listview data all you have to do is assign the FooCollection and it will automatically do the rest for you.
- Eg:

  ```
  public void NewsList_Selected(Object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
  {
       var a = e.SelectedItem as NewsEntry;
       var b = from c in newsEntries
         where (a == c)
         select c;
       foreach(NewsEntry d in b)
      {
        d.Text = d.TextFull;
      }

       FooCollection = newsEntries; // This will do the rest for you 
  }
  ```