# Refresh UI Dotnet Maui

Tags: .net, maui, .net-maui

I have a collection view with a list of items and inside of the data template i have the following:
Viewmodel:

```
[ObservableProperty]
ObservableCollection<InfoService> services;
```

Xaml:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Services}"
                            VerticalOptions="Start"
                            ItemsLayout="VerticalGrid">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="dto:InfoService">
                        <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto" ColumnDefinitions="Auto,Auto,Auto">
                            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding serviceName}" FontSize="Medium"/>
                            <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2">
                                <Label.FormattedText>
                                    <FormattedString>
                                        <Span Text="Barcode: " FontSize="Micro" TextColor="LightGray"/>
                                        <Span Text="{Binding barcode}" FontSize="Micro" TextColor="LightGray"/>
                                    </FormattedString>
                                </Label.FormattedText>
                            </Label>
                            
                        <ImageButton Source="trash.png"
                                     Grid.Column="2" 
                                     Grid.Row="1"
                                     Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:myViewModel}},Path=DeleteServiceCommand}"
                                     CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
```

Command:

```
[RelayCommand]
void DeleteService(InfoService service)
{
    Services.Remove(service);          
    GetTotal();
}
```

The items get deleted but the ui still have the item. Also i want to know if there is a proper way to refresh the ui in similar cases.

Already tried:

- **mainThread InvokeOnMainThread**
- **ObservableCollection // List**

Also if someone can provide an explanation, could be useful for other user since i think could be a common case

Comment: is your `ItemsSource` an `ObservableCollection`?  Does your command actually remove them item from that collection?  Just posting a single line of XAML doesn't really give us much information about what you are doing

Comment: Yes @Jason it's an observable collection and my command actually it's removing the item, i will make an edit now with more info

Comment: I also have an observable Property (Total) wich get's updated on the ui  after i remove the service (with get total method)

Comment: Can I see your CollectionView code where you are Binding the source and the same property in your ViewModel

Comment: @FreakyAli sure, i will edit again

Comment: If possible also add the code where you delete an item..

Comment: @LeandroToloza Can you check if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/53413358/7462031

Comment: @FreakyAli implement INotifyPropertyChanged  it's a possible solution but it supose to work well with observable collection, i think they should be an refresh view method in xaml/maui. i will update this question with possible solutions so it could be helpful for people who is searching the same problem